# Are new redundancies added to a currently ongoing collective redundancy consultation?

Tags: united-kingdom, legal, layoff, food-industry

Acme Corp is currently going through a collective redundancy of more than 100 people from its research and development teams, who help design and make food produce. They are about 30 days into the 45-day collective consultation period. Acme Corp now wants to remove factory workers who package the food produce.

Will this new group go through a separate collective consultation, or will they get added to the currently ongoing collective consultation?

Comment: What goal do you have in mind by finding that out?

Comment: It depends but given the wording I am assuming uk I think  the second group would have its own consultation period you can not shorten the factory workers period in this way - ps talk to the union if you are a member

Comment: @DarkCygnus too see if they are getting screwed on the redundancy process

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research as the two “at risk” groups were notified a month apart the two processes will run independently – your consultation clock won’t reset if that is what you are asking.

Your employer should have consulted with the "at risk" group you are in either via a union or an elected rep/group – they are the best people to ask here if they haven’t consulted properly they will lose automatically  at a tribunal .

Is this Linwoods Health Foods?